# reduce size when pressing the button - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make an animation on the button that when the person presses the button, it decreases its size, and when you click it executes the command normally.

my code:

```
mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "okay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mRegister.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        ObjectAnimator scaleDownX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mRegister, "scaleX", 0.98f);
                        ObjectAnimator scaleDownY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mRegister, "scaleY", 0.98f);

                        ObjectAnimator alpha = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mRegister, "alpha", 0.7f);

                        alpha.setDuration(ACTION_ANIMATION_TIME);

                        scaleDownX.setDuration(ACTION_ANIMATION_TIME);
                        scaleDownY.setDuration(ACTION_ANIMATION_TIME);

                        AnimatorSet scaleDown = new AnimatorSet();
                        scaleDown.play(scaleDownX).with(scaleDownY);
                        scaleDown.play(alpha);

                        scaleDown.start();

                        break;

                    case  MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        ObjectAnimator scaleDownX2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mRegister, "scaleX", 1);
                        ObjectAnimator scaleDownY2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mRegister, "scaleY", 1);

                        ObjectAnimator alpha2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mRegister, "alpha", 1);

                        alpha2.setDuration(ACTION_ANIMATION_TIME);

                        scaleDownX2.setDuration(ACTION_ANIMATION_TIME);
                        scaleDownY2.setDuration(ACTION_ANIMATION_TIME);

                        AnimatorSet scaleDown2 = new AnimatorSet();
                        scaleDown2.play(scaleDownX2).with(scaleDownY2);
                        scaleDown2.play(alpha2);

                        scaleDown2.start();

                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I tried making this code, but the button doesn't execute any commands when you just click, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The easyest way to do that is using a library.
I suggest you to try one of the library below

[Bounceview-Android](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7148)

[AnimatorX](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/8153)

You can find many other library in the [Arsena website](https://android-arsenal.com/). Just take a look in the case you are interrested.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it using scale animation.
You have to make an animation XML & some code to perform such action.

Here is the reference - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bounce-animation-in-android/

Not only bounce or scaling animation, but with this method you can make any desired animation on button click.